# Question on units in a cubic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If $K$ is a cubic extension of $\Bbb Q$ (the rational numbers) having only one real embedding in $\Bbb R$ ( the real numbers), then why should the units in the ring of integers be of the form $\pm u^k$, where $u (>1)$ is the fundamental unit?

I know Dirichlet` theorem of units.

My question is :

1) Why should $\pm 1$ be the only roots of unity in the ring of integers in $K$.

2) Why should $u$ be an integer in $\Bbb Z$, and why should it be $>1$.

This sum is required for problem 35 of chapter 5 of marcus.

Please help. I am stuck with fundamentals...

Comment: What are the roots of unity in the real numbers?  And Marcus is not saying $u$ is in ${\mathbf Z}$, but that it's an integer of $K$. It is not *required* that $u > 1$, but rather than you can find a generating unit that is greater than 1. This is very similar to the structure of the units in a real quadratic field. Do you know what the units looks like in a real quadratic field, and how that can be deduced from Dirichlet's unit theorem?

Comment: Yes, i know for the quadratic case. But why we can find a generating unit that is greater than 1?

Comment: If you apply the Dirichlet unit theorem to a cubic field with one real embedding, what does the theorem say is the number of independent units of infinite order? As for being greater than 1, there is nothing deep going on: among u, 1/u, -u, -1/u, one of them is greater than 1 and can be used in place of u if u is not greater than 1.

Comment: But why we can find a generating unit that is a real number?. If we find one, then the above argument shows that we can find one with value>1. It may happen that all fundamental units are all members of the ring of K , but none of them are real.

Comment: So any extension of number fields which has at least one real embedding has only  +/- 1 as roots of units in th ring of integers. Is it true?

Comment: If a field admits an embedding into the real numbers, where could a root of unity go?

Answer (score 2):

Roots of unity do not fit well inside $\mathbb{R}$: since our field $K$ has a real embedding, this tells us that $K$ only has the second roots of unity.

In the real embedding of $K$, any generator of our unit group is clearly real, and as noted in the comments, there will be a unique generator greater than 1.

However, if we are not considering a real embedding, then it's not the case that the generator must be real. For example, $K=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ is a field with one real embedding. In the real embedding, you may check that $u = 2^{1/3} - 1$ is a fundamental unit greater than 1. If we consider this element in one of the non real embeddings we get, for example, $v = \omega 2^{1/3} - 1$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity--this is definitely not real. The only generators for the non-torsion part of the unit group are $\pm v^{\pm 1}$, none of which are real.

Implicit in the Marcus exercise is that we are considering the real embedding of $K$.