# Fundamental unit on cubic field with only one real inclusion

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I know that if $K$ is a cubic field with only one real inclusion then by Dirichlet's theorem the group of units of its ring of integers $U_K$, would be of the form

$$U_K=\{\pm \varepsilon^n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Now, as asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613348/question-on-units-in-a-cubic-number-field), but in my opinion not answered, my question is why is this fundamental unit a real number?

Comment: Usually one assumes that $K$ is real.

Comment: So, without that assumption it could be the case that units are not real, isn't it?

Comment: I mean, it could be the case that units are not real, but we can always work in the isomorphic real field given by the real inclusion. Is that the reason of the assumption?

Comment: If you work in ${\mathhbb Q(\rho\sqrt[3]{2})$, only the rationals are real. If you pick the real cube root of $2$, every element is real.